# Facebook SDK - How to sort feed data by updated_time?

Tags: php, facebook

I am using Facebook SDK to get my feed data which is sorted by created_time in php.

```
$user_feed = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/feed'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

Does anyone know how to sort it by updated_time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to have custom sort parameters in the Graph API. So, what you want to achieve is currently not possible.